# What am I doing wrong to get group.selected working in graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently trying implement an app to read calendars only for a group that's permitted to the app. The idea behind this is that when I want to add a another calendar all I'd have to do is add the object to a specific o365 group. I'm taking the application approach over delegation that way I don't have anything actually logging in to utilize the app. Ultimately I'd like to stay away from any of the *.All permissions for security reasons.

Steps taken :
- created o365 group
- added resource objects and one user service account (just for testing) to the group 
- registered app
- generated secret
- assigned group to the app
- granted admin consent to groups.selected via the azure portal

When I run a GET  for group/{id}/members :

```
{'error': {'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied', 'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', 'innerError': {'request-id': '473410a8-4db4-49d6-8d2c-92b9fbd4edb1', 'date': '2020-03-05T14:59:28'}}}
```

Comment: Which permission you have set on that? `Dedicated permission`?

Comment: Not sure i understand the question. Is that in regard to the GET request?

Comment: No that's not for `GET` request for sure. It obviously for API permission related issue which is very common.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If you are using Application permissions to Get Members for a group. you will need User.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Directory.Read.All.

The usual issue is not granting that permissions to the application in Portal.azure.com and admin consenting it.

If you're confident with that. Then I'd eliminate your code as being the issue by using something like postman with your app id and client secret. We have a sample Postman collection here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman . for delegated permissions you can use our Graph Explorer playground.

Answer (score 0):

MS docs says:

> Note: This permission is exposed in the Azure portal for a feature that is not available for general use. Do not use this permission as it is subject to change.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference